# query related to RAM

Tags: windows-7, laptop, memory

I am currently using DELL XPS laptop and from some days back whenever install any new game it displays that my RAM is too low to run the game.My laptop has 2nd generation corei7 2.0 GHz processor, 8 GB RAM, 2GB nvidia geforce GT 540N graphics card and the games i have installed are very low requirement games like Counter Strike,Halo.Previously i had played heavy games like battlefield 3, assains creed revelations, modern warefare 3. what do I do??

Comment: When you get that message, use Task Manager (with "Show processes from all users" selected) and Microsoft/Sysinternals RAMMap to see what's using up all your memory.

Comment: What is the "it" that displays this message? And what is the exact message? Are you *sure* it's referring to RAM and not virtual memory, video memory, or some other resource?

Comment: this message can happen if you've disabled the pagefile.

Comment: yes when i tried running halo the message is displayed "you do not have enough virtual memory or RAM to run the game"

Comment: is it possible that my PC is virus infected that is reducing my RAM capacity?

Comment: this message is being displayed only while running the games that i have downloaded 2-3 days back.